Why doesn't the following recursive function terminate and instead leads to a segmentation fault?
I wrote two versions of a function in c to change the color of a coherent area of white pixels on a canvas by checking the color of the starting coordinate and, if the staring coordinate is white, set it to black. Afterwards all adjacent pixels (up, down, left, right) are processed in the same manner by recursively calling the same function with updated coordinates:
//faulty version - does not terminate:
Canvas bucket_fill_fail(Canvas c, int x, int y) {

//check if pixel is white and within borders of canvas
if (!pixel_is_black(c, x, y) && x >= 0 && x < canvas_width(c) && y >= 0 && y < canvas_height(c))
    {
        c = canvas_set_black(c, x, y);
        c = bucket_fill_fail(c, x + 1, y);  //right
        c = bucket_fill_fail(c, x - 1, y);  //left
        c = bucket_fill_fail(c, x, y + 1);  //up
        c = bucket_fill_fail(c, x, y - 1);  //down
    }
    return c;
}



//version works as intended:
Canvas bucket_fill_works(Canvas c, int x, int y) {

//is pixel within borders of canvas?
if (x >= 0 && x < canvas_width(c) && y >= 0 && y < canvas_height(c)) {

    //is pixel white?
    if (!pixel_is_black(c, x, y))
    {
        c = canvas_set_black(c, x, y);
        c = bucket_fill_works(c, x + 1, y);  //right
        c = bucket_fill_works(c, x - 1, y);  //left
        c = bucket_fill_works(c, x, y + 1);  //up
        c = bucket_fill_works(c, x, y - 1);  //down
    }
}

return c;
}

Version 1 seems to endlessly iterate through the recursive part regardless of the color of the current pixel, which leads to a segmentation fault.
I managed to fix the issue by separately checking, if the pixel is within the canvas borders and only then checking the color before entering the recursive part (as shown in version 2). But I cant figure out why the first version doesn't lead to the same result and is getting stuck in an endless loop instead. From my understanding, both versions should do the same thing.
I know this is probably some realy basic stuff, I'm an absolute beginner and can't figure out were I'm in the wrong.

In the first version you go into the recursion before checking if x or y are out of bounds. In the second version you never go into the recursion if x or y are out of bounds, this is a huge difference. Add a printf("%d %d\n", x, y); right at the beginning of the function and check the output for both cases.

Showing a [mcve] (with a very simple canvas) might help as well. While doing this, you'll probably find out yourself what the problem is.

Note that you could do if (x >= 0 && x < canvas_width(c) && y >= 0 && y < canvas_height(c) && !pixel_is_black(c, x, y)) since pixel_is_black will then not be called unless all the other conditions are true due to short circuiting.

I would distinguish the 4 borders of the canvas when checking... ( x+1 may work while x-1 may not work...)

Why was this taken out of staging ground?

This has nothing to do with recursion. Unless pixel_is_black can handle x and y out of bounds, then naturally you will need to check that those are valid before calling the function, as is done in the second version.
Note that && has strict left-to-right evaluation. Placing pixel_is_black to the far right of the && chain would be equivalent to the separate if in the second version.
